# Menu bar does not show up on macOS

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I wrote this code on Pycharm (macOS) but the menu bar does not show up. Can anyone tell me why?

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()


    def hello():
        print("hello!")


   # create a toplevel menu
   menubar = Menu(root)
   menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
   menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=root.destroy)

   # display the menu
   root.config(menu=menubar)
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put commands at the very top of a menubar in OSX. Also, the menu will not appear at the top of the window, it appears at the top of the screen just like with native OSX apps.

Other than the fact that your menubar has no dropdown menus, it's working as designed. Add a dropdown menu, and that menu will appear on the menubar.

Comment: how to add dropdown menubar ?

Comment: @AnnieDhawan: just read the documentation or work through a tutorial. https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html#menubars